# Check whether two vertices are connected using graph-tool on Python

Tags: python, graph-tool, complex-networks

Is there a method in graph-tool through which checking whether two nodes are connected (as first neighbours) or not without having to iterate?

For example, something like `graph_tool.is_connected(v,u)` which returns a boolean depending on whether `v` and `u` are or not connected vertices. Something like a function to check just whether a certain edge exists.

Thanks

Comment: Just a guess: Since an existing edge between vertices given by index 0 and 1 can be accessed as `e = g.edge(0,1)`, maybe you can do `i=g.vertex_index(u); j=g.vertex_index(v); try: e = g.edge(i,j); except ...`?

Answer (score 1):

It is solved by checking the result of the function `g.edge(v,u)`. If `add_missing=False` it just returns `None` whenever the edge does not exist. Thanks to @NerdOnTour for the comment

Comment: Nice. I think you have a typo and actually mean `add_missing==False`?